# QGIS 2.8.9 - problem printing maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

I have a problem printing map out of Composer. I need to print Corine Land Cover but when I try to print the map, many of corine layers aren't visible on the printed map. They are loaded in project and visible in it, but when I try to print them to PDF, many of them disappear.

Is this because of too many data?
This is project preview. As you can see, all data is loaded in visible.
[image]

And this is the result - visible only few layers, but not all.
I tried to close and open the program, refresh project and composer, print to JPG, but result is the same.
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.